# Get RGB component order of a display

Tags: rgb

To reliably do sub-pixel rendering the algorithm needs to know the physical component order of the attached display, i.e. is it RGB or BGR or... 
I've checked on Mac and Windows but have yet to find any API where I can retrieve this information.
Ideas ?

Comment: What order are [triangular pixels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_geometry) in, RGB or BGR?

Comment: Those are mainly used in CRTs, however that is a "dying breed", so I don't concern myself much with it.